# Why plugin jQuery AJAX selector not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

My plugin:

```
 (function ($) {
 $.fn.Conniction_With_DB = function () {
 this.focusout(function () {
        var Val = this.val();
         alert(Val);
 };
 })(jQuery);
```

Call my plugin:

```
 <script src="../js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        // jquery API
 <script src="../js/JQ_Plug_Ins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   // jquery Plugin

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         $('input:text').Conniction_With_DB();
    });
 </script>
```

The question is : why doesn't my plugin respond when I call it?

PS : I think the error in the plugin is in this part (`this.focusout`) .... 
or in the calling plugin in this part (`$('input:text')`) ....

Comment: What version of jquery? .focusout was added in 1.4

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error, you forgot some braces (line 6), and you have to use `$(this).val()`, not `this.val()`. `this` will be the DOM object inside the `focusout` callback, not the jQuery object.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.Conniction_With_DB = function () {
        this.focusout(function () {
            var Val = $(this).val();
            alert(Val);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```